# I'm looking for research institutions focusing on coaching

Tags: motivation, leadership

Please tell me about universities and research institutes conducting research on coaching. Ideally, I'm looking for places that have researchers, publish papers, and engage in academic activities like presenting at conferences. If you have information on the departments, disciplines, or lab names, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.